# Apache PHP modules not upgraded in 22.04

Tags: upgrade, apache2, php, 22.04

After upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04, Apache server does not start anymore:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so: cannot open shared object file

Here the PHP package installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep php8
ii  libapache2-mod-php8.0                      8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        Transitional package
ii  libapache2-mod-php8.1                      8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-symfony-polyfill-php80                 1.24.0-1ubuntu2                         all          Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions
ii  php-symfony-polyfill-php81                 1.24.0-1ubuntu2                         all          Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.1+ features to lower PHP versions
rc  php8.0-bz2                                 8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
rc  php8.0-cli                                 8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
rc  php8.0-common                              8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
rc  php8.0-curl                                8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        CURL module for PHP
rc  php8.0-gd                                  8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        GD module for PHP
rc  php8.0-intl                                8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        Internationalisation module for PHP
rc  php8.0-mbstring                            8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
rc  php8.0-mysql                               8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        MySQL module for PHP
rc  php8.0-opcache                             8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
rc  php8.0-readline                            8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        readline module for PHP
rc  php8.0-xml                                 8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, XML, and XSL module for PHP
rc  php8.0-zip                                 8.0.8-1ubuntu0.3                        amd64        Zip module for PHP
ii  php8.1-bz2                                 8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        bzip2 module for PHP
ii  php8.1-cli                                 8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php8.1-common                              8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php8.1-curl                                8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php8.1-gd                                  8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php8.1-mbstring                            8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php8.1-mysql                               8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php8.1-opcache                             8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php8.1-readline                            8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php8.1-xml                                 8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, XML, and XSL module for PHP
ii  php8.1-zip                                 8.1.2-1ubuntu2                          amd64        Zip module for PHP
```

The available librarie is:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5354272 apr  7 19:46 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.1.so
```

Here the content of the offending mods:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.0.load
# Conflicts: php5
# Depends: mpm_prefork
LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so
```

Changing it to `libphp8.1.so` leads to apache2 service restarts correctly.

Why it didn't update this file?
What should I do to avoid this manually hacking?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved as above using the following steps:

1. Remove the old php 8.0 references in `mods-enabled` directory.
2. Add new symbolic links in `mods-enabled` to the php 8.1 references in the `mods-available` directory.

The steps followed are outlined below:

**Before the resolution:**

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled  
$ ls -l \*php\*  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 May 29 20:27 php8.0.conf -> ../mods-available/php8.0.conf  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 May 29 20:27 php8.0.load -> ../mods-available/php8.0.load
```

**Implement the resolution:**

```
$ sudo rm php8.0.conf php8.0.load  
$ sudo ln -s ../mods-available/php8.1.load php8.1.load  
$ sudo ln -s ../mods-available/php8.1.conf php8.1.conf
```

**After the resolution:**

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled  
$ ls -l \*php\*  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun  3 12:36 php8.1.conf -> ../mods-available/php8.1.conf  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun  3 12:36 php8.1.load -> ../mods-available/php8.1.load
```

**Test:**

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2  
$ sudo systemctl status apache2  
* apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-06-03 12:37:30 BST; 5s ago
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not actually answer to my questions because I've already provided kink of solution as workaround. I was asking *why* this happens and if there is anything we can do to avoid this manual fix. In other words, they released a bugged update?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for quite a long time, this was the final solution: https://idroot.us/install-php-7-4-ubuntu-22-04/

Just followed the steps and my PHP website was up and running again.

Edit: steps below

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install wget apt-transport-https gnupg2 software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2 php7.4 php7.4 php7.4-common libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-cli
sudo apt install php7.4 php7.4-fpm php7.4-cli
```

Comment: Could you put the steps in instead of just the link? It’s better to do that in case the link breaks. Thanks!